# How to break out of for-loop using condition statement in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, dos, break

I am doing some processing of a large number of files, and I want to limit what I'm doing to the first 9 files found. I have tried this in a batch file and it does not work. It processes for all the files, and does not stop at the 9th one. What have I done wrong?

```
setlocal
set fileCount=0

for %%I in (*.doc) do (
  rem do stuff here ...
  set /a fileCount+=1
  if "%fileCount%"=="9" exit
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `%fileCount%` is being expanded during parse-time rather than during execution-time, so it doesn't take into account the changes to `fileCount` during the course of execution. So your `for`-loop is equivalent to this:

```
for %%I in (*.doc) do (
  rem do stuff here ...
  set /a fileCount+=1
  if "0"=="9" exit
)
```

To correct it, you need to enable and use delayed expansion. You do that by using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` rather than merely `setlocal`, and `!fileCount!` rather than `%fileCount%`. So:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set fileCount=0

for %%I in (*.doc) do (
  rem do stuff here ...
  set /a fileCount+=1
  if "!fileCount!"=="9" exit
)
```

For more information, see http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't catch that I left out EnableDelayedExpansion! I'd been back and forth with the ! and % and other variations on the fileCount variable. Thanks again!